# Performance and ease of use for embedding or calling R from Java on Linux Systems

Tags: java, r

I am soliciting up-to-date feedback  on a specific use case of R/Java integration:

- integrating R and R libraries into a JVM based app (java/scala) on a Linux environment (Deb/Ubuntu and Centos/RHEL in particular).

  - what options provide good performance when working with medium amounts of data - in the few to maybe 10 GB range
  - which options are easier to debug in terms of the actual R code being invoked. That is, if an R function fails, how do we troubleshoot it , when we are starting from the calling java application.

In a nutshell, I want to consider both performance and ease of use. It may be that more than one solution makes sense, depending on the relative importance of performance. I.e. something like Rcaller is faster but more primitive.

Historical Note: I realize there is a similar SOF question but it is 15 months old and a bit more general.

[Java-R integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451716/java-r-integration)

It is showing its age: Some of the links on that page are already stale. I am looking for new information. thanks!

Comment: There was a single 404-ed link and it has been now replaced. On the separate question of recovery from error have you done searching in SO with:  `java error  [r]` ?

Comment: I pored through that older one and it really is out of date: the stale links were a symptom not the cause.  Also this question is focused on  specific bullet items that make it distinct from the earlier one.

Comment: The way to keep up to date is to subscribe to the rosuda-stats At the moment your question seems broad, unfocused, and lacking in evidence of effort at searching prior postings in SO. Perhaps you can improve it?

Comment: This question has a narrower scope / is more focused than the earlier one and i ran your search it did not bring up directly relevant results to my inquiry.  I would request the opportunity for other persons also in the field to provide their feedback.