# Java: datastructure for a table with typeparameter for row, column and value

Tags: java, collections

I am looking for a datastructure like a table where the type of row, column and value are parametrizable. Value is the cell of row/column.

Is there something compareable in any common java library?

```
     | col1  | col2  | ...
-------------+-------+----
row1 | val11 | val12 | ...
row2 | val21 | val22 | ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there was no built in Tables. But even in this design, what will you be able to achieve without the standard queries? You might want to rethink your design if your approach is just to have tables, visualization and what coded may be different.

But alternatively you may try:

1. Build a multi dimensional array (limited with same data type).
2. The standard of list of objects/classes. i.e. list.add(new Data(col1, col2));
3. Look into [Guava's Library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table) on Table.
4. Checkout other libraries, in particular for the keyword [DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540831/java-object-analogue-to-r-data-frame). It's a key for many analytical tools.

Comment: Building it by myself would be not a big problem. But maybe there is already something out there. I will have a look into the libs you referenced.

Comment: Guava.Table is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

In java this data structure is typically represented as a list of objects of the same type, each object equates to a row.  It's so easy to just do a list of objects that it doesn't have any other implementation (or even name).

It can also be a list of maps where each map has the same keys (making it very similar to a list of objects)

If you query SQL in Groovy, this is exactly the structure you get back--so I got used to thinking of it as a unique data structure.

Although you often won't find a collection for this exact data structure (I suppose because a list of objects is just too common), it is nice to recognize this as a data structure for the purposes of utilities.

For instance, in Groovy I have a utility that takes a list of maps and dumps it out in ascii (much like your drawing), and a second that dumps one to a swing table object--neither of these take any parameters except for the list of maps (or objects, groovy doesn't differentiate) since it can calculate column names from the map keys.