# Operation on RList

Tags: java, r, list

I have the following code.

```
public void rFun() {

    Rsession instance = RConnect.getInstance();
    instance.eval("load(\".RData\")");

    REXP x = instance.eval("xyz <- c(10,20,30)");

    try {
        System.out.println("xyz -> "+x.asString());

    } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am creating an RList, but when I try to get the list in java it is displaying only the first value i.e. `10`.

How to get all the values of the list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java-R integration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451716/java-r-integration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop and get the values.

```
for(int i=0; i<x.asInteger(); i++){
    System.out.println(x.asStrings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
x.asDoubleMatrix()[][]
```

for data frames or matrices containing numeric or integer values.